# Radiobuttons $_request values

Tags: php, smarty

I have a code for a radiobutton form with images as buttons:

```
<label class="desc" id="title6" for="Field6i5" style="color: #5f5f5f;">
Choose color
</label>

<input type="radio" name="color" id="gray" class="input-hidden" value="" checked/>
<label for="gray" style="width: 40px;"><img src="images/gray.png" alt=""  />


<input type="radio" name="color" id="gold" class="input-hidden" value=""/>
<label for="gold" style="width: 40px;"><img src="images/gold.png" alt="" />


<input type="radio" name="color" id="silver" class="input-hidden" value=""/>
<label for="silver" style="width: 40px;"><img src="images/silver.png" alt="" />
```

Now in the form processing PHP I wanted to make $_REQUEST for the color that user chose in the radiobutton. How do I do that? I wanted to get it and send a confirmation mail

```
$send_data['Field6i5']['label'] = "Color";
$send_data['Field6i5']['value'] = $_REQUEST['Field6i5'];
```

And email description in smarty is:

```
You've chosen:    {$send_data.Field6i5.value}
```

I am little confused with what I am passing this... value, name or id :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find which radio button was selected you need to look at the value of `$_REQUEST['color']` because you have called the radio button set `name="color"`

The contents of `$_REQUEST['color']` will be whatever you place in the input fields `value=""` attribute.

So you need to put a unique value into the `value=""` attribute for each radio button

```
<input type="radio" name="color" id="gray" class="input-hidden" value="gray" checked/>
<label for="gray" style="width: 40px;"><img src="images/gray.png" alt=""  />


<input type="radio" name="color" id="gold" class="input-hidden" value="gold"/>
<label for="gold" style="width: 40px;"><img src="images/gold.png" alt="" />


<input type="radio" name="color" id="silver" class="input-hidden" value="silver"/>
<label for="silver" style="width: 40px;"><img src="images/silver.png" alt="" />
```

Now in your PHP you can access which radiobutton was selected using `$_REQUEST['color']`

```
$send_data['Field6i5']['label'] = "Color";
$send_data['Field6i5']['value'] = $_REQUEST['color'];
```

Comment: Thanks man, it works! :)
I've been starring at the code for too long and all those values, id and names became one for me ;)